# classList.add() & setTimeout for remove NOT WORKING IN LOOP INSIDE A FUNCTION

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, settimeout

setTimeout not working as expected,

classList.add works but when add setTimeout for classList.remove it shows an erron in console as

"VM1578:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

```
var clrArr = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"];

var randomClr = [];

//Random Color. Gen

function noGen() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
}

function randomClrGen() {
    var no = noGen();
    randomClr.push(clrArr[no]);
    console.log(randomClr);    
}

function randomBtnPress() {
    randomClrGen();
    for(var i = 0; i<randomClr.length; i++){
    document.querySelector("."+ randomClr[i]).classList.add("pressed");
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector("."+ randomClr[i]).classList.remove("pressed");        
    },100);
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `let i = 0` instead of var. When using var the context of `i` is lost by the time setTimeout runs.

Comment: but one doubt.. both add and setTimeout in the same for loop, so value of " i " should remain till last , right ??

Comment: The add happens sync. The remove happens async (because of the setTimeout).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `randomClrGen` only once. So, `randomClr` holds only one value. You may call `randomClrGen` inside the `for..loop`:

```
var clrArr = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "green"];

var randomClr = [];

//Random Color. Gen

function noGen() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
}

function randomClrGen() {
    var no = noGen();
    randomClr.push(clrArr[no]);
    console.log(randomClr);    
}

function randomBtnPress() {
    
    for(let i = 0; i<clrArr.length; i++){
   
    randomClrGen();
    document.querySelector("."+ randomClr[i]).classList.add("pressed");
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector("."+ randomClr[i]).classList.remove("pressed");        
    },100);
    };

}

randomBtnPress()
```

Comment: Good point. That'll be their next problem. Here's another take on it: randomClr = clrArr.map(()=>clrArr[Math.floor(clrArr.length*Math.random())])

Comment: @JayB yeah the first version of mime was something similar. Then I thought of suggesting the minimal changes.

Comment: if randomClrGen() called inside for loop, randomClr.length will be zero, so for loop won't execute.

Comment: @AJMALKAREEM that's a good catch. Let me update that.

Answer (score 0):

use method bind() for callback function

```
function randomBtnPress() {
    
    randomClrGen();
    for( var i = 0; i<randomClr.length; i++){
    document.querySelector("."+ randomClr[i]).classList.add("pressed");
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        document.querySelector("."+ randomClr[i]).classList.remove("pressed");        
    }.bind(null,i),100);// here in this line
    };

}
```

Comment: not working same result.. changed var i to let i, and it worked, thanks for the reply